# Ruby on Rails: How to validate if on specific page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Ruby on Rails application I am trying to add in validations that will ensure the user has entered a value in a text box. In my system I have a table called `Account` which stores users' email account information, when they go onto the `views/accounts/_form.html.erb` page to add a new email account I want to validate the presence of a port number. I can do this through the following code:

```
validates :port, presence: true
```

This successfully ensures that users enter their port number, but when a user signs up through the `views/users/_new.html.erb` page they have to enter only an email address (e.g example@example.com) and the `users_controller` will then  create a record in the `Account` table for this email address. My problem is that on the `views/accounts/_form.html.erb` page the port number is required but on the `views/users/_new.html.erb` it is not.

Is there a way of validating that the user enters the port number if they are on the `views/accounts/_form.html.erb` page or invoking the `create` method in the `accounts_controller`?

I am aware that I could do this through the HTML required validation like so: `<%= f.text_field :port, :required => true %>` but I need to add in further validation as well as presence, so this is not suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an `attr_accessor` field that determines if the validation should occur...

```
class Account < ActiveRecord:Base
  attr_accessor :port_needs_validation
  validates :port, presence: true, if: -> {port_needs_validation}
```

Then just set the accessor in your create method...

```
def create
  @account = Account.new
  @account.assign_attributes(account_params)
  @account.port_needs_validation = true
  if @account.save
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract that part of the logic into a form object, check out the [legendary 2012 blog entry from CodeClimate](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/). Things have changed since then, the author uses `Virtus` to build form objects, more popular & up-to-date gems these days are:

- [reform](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform)
- [dry-rb](http://cucumbersome.net/2016/09/06/rails-form-objects-with-dry-rb.html)
- [active type](https://github.com/makandra/active_type)
- [but really you can make anything behave like an ActiveModel object](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/)

if it's a one-off thing, just do [what Steve said in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856958/ruby-on-rails-how-to-validate-if-on-specific-page/41857176#41857176) but that is a sure way to hell, safe-hate and divorce (at least from personal experience) in any *slightly teeny weeny* bigger project (i.e. you mean to spend some hours more working on it, it's not like you just finished everything and want to go home).

Actually, just use form classes everywhere and avoid model validations & other callbacks at all. You don't want things sending account activation mails or validating your password complexity when you're writing tests and just need a "post" that belongs to "user".

My own favorite personal fuckup due to model callbacks is sending 240.000 "your account has been upgraded/downgraded" emails because of an innocent spelling change update in an `account_type` attribute migration just because  `account_type_changed?` was true.

So.. Form classes for ever, model callbacks never.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you have `model` aware of `views`. In @SteveTurczyn 's solution, an abstract field is introduced into model to identified the which page it come from, which is an good solution.

As from [Ruby on Rail MVC](https://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/), both `View` and `Model` talk to the controller, another solution will be have controller handle **validation** of params before passing the value to create `account`.